# Loss data when transmitting notifications on BLE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have problems with BLE on Samsung and Google Pixel devices. I have a peripheral that has both Bluetooth Lower Energy and Bluetooth classic channels. First, I connected the audio channel to my phone and connected the BLE channel to my app on the phone. The peripheral then started transmitting data to the phone via BLE notifications and the phone plays several tracks simultaneously.
The peripheral sends a 178-byte packet with an interval of 72ms. Each packet has a sequence number in the header from 0 to 255 and repeats.
When the RSSI is stable (< -60), everything is fine, but when the distance between the peripheral and the phone increases, the RSSI becomes weak, and data is lost. The payload received on the phone was interrupted (I checked the sequence number). After that, I brought the phone and the peripheral closer, RSSI became strong again, but the data loss continued. But if I stop playing music, the data loss disappears immediately. When I press playback, the data loss continued.

Checking the HCI snoop log on the phone, I see that when data is lost, the 178 bytes payload data is split into multiple 32 bytes packets and reassembled. This issue only occurs on Samsung and Google Pixel devices. I tested on Vivo, Oppo, and even iPhone and did not encounter this phenomenon.

Is there any way to remove this packet splitting mechanism on Android? And if I can't get rid of it, is there any way to reconfigure the mechanism to not split packets like the original?

Has anyone encountered this problem? Please suggest me, thanks.

**Update:**
1 - From our firmware log, we can see an error "not enough resource - Error 17" for a specific package. Once the package is dropped, the firmware continues to send other packages (with increased sequence numbers) with a smaller size (MTU). In particular, we started out with MTU = 247 but after congestion, MTU = 32. It stays so once the congestion happens. This low MTU keeps the connection inefficient, hences package loss persist.
Do you have any guesstion on how to pull the MTU back to 247 after the congestion is over?

2 - Why don't we have this problem with other phones such as iPhone, Oppo?

3 - Here is our current internal setting on our firmware:

```
    /*  Using 90mS interval to not be at same frequency as advertising interval of peer 
    using 100% duty cycle to ensure fastest connection possible.
    Note that although this is a 100% duty cycle the Bluetooth controller may interrupt 
    this to take account of other activities. */
#define LE_FIXED_PARAMS \
    .scan_interval              = 144, \
    .scan_window                = 144, \
    .supervision_timeout        = 400, \
    .conn_attempt_timeout       = 50, \
    .conn_latency_max           = 64, \
    .supervision_timeout_min    = 400, \
    .supervision_timeout_max    = 400, \
    .own_address_type           = TYPED_BDADDR_PUBLIC

/* Taken from sink app slave parameters */
#define LE_LP_CONNECTION_PARAMS \
    .conn_interval_min  = CONN_INT_MS(90), \
    .conn_interval_max  = CONN_INT_MS(110), \
    .conn_latency       = 4

static const ble_connection_params low_power_connection_params = 
{
    LE_FIXED_PARAMS, LE_LP_CONNECTION_PARAMS
};

/* Taken from sink app master initial parameters */
#define LE_LL_CONNECTION_PARAMS \
    .conn_interval_min  = CONN_INT_MS(30), \
    .conn_interval_max  = CONN_INT_MS(50), \
    .conn_latency       = 0

static const ble_connection_params low_latency_connection_params = 
{
    LE_FIXED_PARAMS, LE_LL_CONNECTION_PARAMS
};

/*! Settings used on an LE Audio link when it is idle. */
#define LEA_IDLE_CONNECTION_PARAMS \
    .conn_interval_min  = CONN_INT_MS(60), \
    .conn_interval_max  = CONN_INT_MS(90), \
    .conn_latency       = 0

static const ble_connection_params lea_idle_connection_params = 
{
    LE_FIXED_PARAMS, LEA_IDLE_CONNECTION_PARAMS
};
```

Do you suggest to change the number of conn_interval and conn_latency?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you see the lost packets in the hci log, i.e. are the packets lost somewhere between the Bluetooth stack and the app (running on the same phone)? Or don't you even see the packets in the hci log?

Comment: @Emil I don't see lost packets in the hci log.

Comment: @user1767221 can you please check if the MTU method is available or not? MTU will allow you to increase the size of the payload.

Comment: @user1955086 I called  requestMtu(512) before transmitting data and the MTU returned 247.

Answer (score 1):

Since the BLE link layer is a reliable protocol, no packets get lost over the air unless disconnection happens. If you don't see an expected packet in the hci log, it means the sender doesn't even send it in the first place. Please check your firmware code, especially your flow control how you handle the case when you want to send more data or more often than the link can sustain. Bluetooth throughput is a shared resource so it's not strange that your throughput is reduced to/from your peripheral if you stream audio at the same time.

The packet splitting mechanism you are referring to is when an L2CAP paket gets split up into multiple link layer packets. The LE Data Length Extension is used to negotiate the maximum packet size in each direction. Typically, Android seems to align this with the chosen ATT MTU size. But it's possible that it gets lowered when audio is played (not sure but I know the Android team has done a lot of tweaks to optimise for good audio quality). You will typically see this negotiation in the hci log.

If the radio scheduler needs to interrupt a connection event after one or more round trips, even though any device has the "more data" flag set, e.g. to handle your audio stream, this could explain why you see a throughput reduction. This code runs inside the Bluetooth controller (Bluetooth chip) and not inside the host (Android).

A typical solution you can do is to lower the connection interval. This will increase the opportunities your peripheral can send data. You can combine this with "peripheral latency" to allow the peripheral to skip connection events where it does not have any new data to send.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Please check my update for more details.